# How to select a component element with protractor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, protractor

I have component "Add New" which is actually button.
Already tried select with adding css, id, className and by that select element but still I'm is not visible.

Method in protractor which should select "Add New" -button.

```
  clickAddNewBtn() {
      console.log("Click on Add New button.");
      return element(by.css('.add-new')).click();
  }
```

Html: "Add New" button (component):

```
import { Component, Output, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'nano-add-new-button',
    template: `
    <div class='nano-f-r nano-f add-new'>
        <i class='fa fa-plus'></i>
           <span class='nano-ml-5 add-new'>
                Add New
           </span>
    </div>`
})
export class NanoAddNewButtonComponent {
}
```

Any Idea why I cant select some class id or selector of component Add new button?

audience.e2e-spec.ts: Spec test file:

```
describe('Category Rule functionality', () => {
  let loginPage: LoginPage;
  let audiencePage: AudiencePage;


  beforeEach(() => {
    loginPage = new LoginPage();
    audiencePage = new AudiencePage();
  });

  it('Auto QA bot should be able to make new Category rule and save.', () => {

    console.log("Navigate on login page");
    loginPage.navigateTo();

    console.log("Fill login form");    
    loginPage.fillCredentials();

    console.log("After login go to Audience tab"); 
    audiencePage.goToAudienceTab();

    audiencePage.clickAddNewBtn();

    audiencePage.typeTextInAudienceNameField();

    audiencePage.pickRangeLast14Days();

    audiencePage.selectCategoryRule();

    audiencePage.typeTextInCategoryRuleTextArea();

    audiencePage.clickSaveBtn();

    expect(audiencePage.getNotification()).toEqual('Audience saved');
  });
});
```

Audience.po.ts file:

```
 export class AudiencePage {

  navigateTo() {
    return browser.get('/private/audience');
  }

  goToAudienceTab() {
    return element(by.xpath('/html/body/nano-app/nano-private/nano-navigation/div/div[3]/a/span')).click();
  }

  clickAddNewBtn() {
    console.log("Click on Add New button.");
    return element(by.tagName('nano-add-new-button')).click();
  }

  typeTextInAudienceNameField() {
    console.log("Type text in audience name field");
    return element(by.css('.nano-white-smoke-input')).sendKeys('Test');
  }

  pickRangeLast14Days() {
    return element(by.xpath('/html/body/nano-app/nano-private/nano-modal/div/div/div/div/nano-modal-entity/nano-audience-edit/form/div/div[2]/nano-audience-date-range/div[2]/label[2]/span'));
  }

  openRuleDropdown() {
    return element(by.xpath('/html/body/nano-app/nano-private/nano-modal/div/div/div/div/nano-modal-entity/nano-audience-edit/form/div/nano-audience-rules/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/nano-drop-down/div/button/div/span')).click();
  }

  selectCategoryRule() {
    return element(by.xpath('/html/body/nano-app/nano-private/nano-modal/div/div/div/div/nano-modal-entity/nano-audience-edit/form/div/nano-audience-rules/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/nano-drop-down/div/ul/li[5]/button/div/span')).click();
  }

  typeTextInCategoryRuleTextArea() {
    return element(by.xpath('/html/body/nano-app/nano-private/nano-modal/div/div/div/div/nano-modal-entity/nano-audience-edit/form/div/nano-audience-rules/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/nano-category-rule/div/textarea')).sendKeys('Test');
  }

  clickAddRuleBtn() {
    return element(by.name('button .nano-c-p')).click();
  }

  clickSaveBtn() {
    return element(by.id('save')).click();
  }

  getNotification() {
    return element(by.xpath('notification')).getText();
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem might be with your protractor setup, like if you are not waiting for the elements to render. You need to show your full e2e-test-class and config.

Comment: Ok I will edit the post and add full test.

Comment: Added entire both files

Comment: Are you sure you have a click-event handler for the button? and that the click-handler is not on the inner `add-new` of the span, but the outer div? I do not see any (click) there in your code... Or do you not get any element querying it like this? 

If so, perhaps you need to do ` await browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css('.add-new'))), 5000)}` in the page-object-method and make that method `async` (and prepend to the call to it in the spec-file an `await`).

Comment: Yes, here is (click) listener, now: http://prntscr.com/jglgze
Now is fine. Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide your own answer to this? It looks like this has been solved?

Comment: At the moment I was sure that I solve it. But problem is still active. 
When I find solution I will provide answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is select "add new" class from Add New by all locator.

```
clickAddNewBtn() {
    console.log("Click on Add New button.");
    return element.all(by.css('add new'));;
}
```